# C++ std::string InputIterator code to C code

Tags: c++, c, string

I have some C++ code that I found that does exactly what I need, however I need it in C and I do not know how I could do it in C, so I am hoping someone can help me out.

The C++ code is:

`std::string value( (const char *)valueBegin, (const char *)valueEnd );`

This is using the string::string constructor:

`template<class InputIterator> string (InputIterator begin, InputIterator end);`

Can anyone help me in converting this to C code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Get the number of characters in the range
size_t length = valueEnd - valueBegin;

// Allocate one more for the C style terminating 0
char *data = malloc(length + 1);

// Copy just the number of bytes requested
strncpy(data, valueBegin, length);

// Manually add the C terminating 0
data[length] = '\0';
```

Comment: The `malloc()`'d memory will need to be `free()`'d as well.

Comment: Also to not cause a warning the second parameter of strncpy needs to be casted to: (const char *)

Comment: @kdbdallas - what is the type of valueBegin?  I assumed it was a `char *` which would mean you shouldn't need a cast for strncpy.  If it is not a `char *` or `const char *`, you may need to reevaluate the subtraction in the first ine.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ code creates new string from substring of another string. Similiar functionality in C is `strndup`:

```
char *str = strndup(valueBegin, valueEnd - valueBegin);
// ...
free(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

By assuming that pointer arithmetic make sense in your situation:

```
strncpy( value, valueBegin, valueEnd-valueBegin );
```

Comment: His example creates `value` as an automatic variable, but you're assuming `value` is a pointer to valid memory.